# Is there an easy way to check who has a reader lock or a writer lock in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

A AcquireReaderLock is failing and I suspect that it is because someone else is holding on to the lock indefinitely. Does Visual Studio 2010 provide an easy way of checking who has the reader lock or writer lock? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not easily at least.

You can use something like JetBrains dotTrace which will allow you to go into the bowels of the call stack to figure out where things are getting held up.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Answer (score 1):

Well, that cannot possibly be the explanation.  Another thread holding a reader lock doesn't block you from acquiring a reader lock.  Reads can be shared.  The only possible explanation is that a thread holds the-one-and-only writer lock.  That's visible in the debugger, the private _dwWriterID field holds the ManagedID of the thread that owns it.  Match it to the thread you see in the Debug + Windows + Threads window.  VS2010 displays the managed ID, earlier versions do not.  Double-click it and switch to the call stack window to see what this thread is doing.